# Pushing key/value pair data to graphite/grafana

Tags: visualization, monitoring, metrics, grafana, graphite

We are trying to see if graphite will fit our use case. So we have a number of public parameters. Like key value pairs.
Say:

Data: 
Caller:abc
Site:xyz
Http status: 400
6-7 more similar fields (key values pairs) .

Etc.

This data is continuously posted to use in a data report.  What we want is to draw visualisations over this data.

We want graphs that will say things like how many 400s by sites etc. Which are the top sites or callers for whom there is 400.

Now we are wondering if this can be done with graphite.

But we have questions. Graphite store numerical values. So how will we represent this in graphite.

Something like this ?

```
Clicks.metric.status.400 1 currTime
Clicks.metric.site.xyz 1 currTime
Clicks.metric.caller.abc 1 currTime
```

Adding 1 as the numerical value to record the event.

Also how will we group the set of values together.

For eg this http status is for this site as it is one record.
In that case we need something like

```
Clicks.metric.status.{uuid1}.400 1 currTime
Clicks.metric.site.{uuid1}.xyz 1 currTime
```

Our aim is to then use grafana to have graphs on this data as in what are the top site which have are showing 400 status? 
will this is ok ? 
regards

Answer (score 1):

Graphite accepts three types of data: [plaintext, pickled, and AMQP](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/feeding-carbon.html).

> The plaintext protocol is the most straightforward protocol supported
>   by Carbon.
>
> The data sent must be in the following format: `<metric path> <metric
>   value> <metric timestamp>`. Carbon will then help translate this line
>   of text into a metric that the web interface and Whisper understand.

---

If you're new to graphite (which sounds like you are) plaintext is definitely the easiest to get going with.

As to how you'll be able to group metrics and perform operations on them, you have to remember that graphite doesn't natively *store* any of this for you. It stores [timeseries metrics](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/timeseries.html), and provides functions that manipulate that data for visual / reporting purposes. So when you send a metric, `prod.host-abc.application-xyz.grpc.GetStatus.return-codes.400 1 1522353885`, all you're doing is storing the value `1` for that specific metric at timestamp `1522353885`. You can then use graphite functions to display that data, e.g.,:  `sumSeries(prod.*.application-xyz.grpc.GetStatus.return-codes.400)` will produce a `sum` of all `400` error codes from all hosts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am indeed new to Graphite and I think I will need to use the plain-text format. I will go through the solution you suggested and will see how it goes. One question I had was can these functions like sumSeries to applied to more than one metric like 'status' and 'site' or something ?